# The right way to read /dev/oldmem?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to read raw memory from the /dev/oldmem device. However, when I try to use the `dd` command to read from the device, I end up only with a file of size 4096 bytes or 4KB, rather than the complete memory dump.

The `dd` command I used was:
 `sudo dd if=/dev/oldmem of=/tmp/om`

Here, `/tmp/om` should be a copy of the `oldmem` contents. But it is always coming out to be 4KB. Is there something wrong in my approach? Is there something that I missing here? My only goal is to view the complete memory of the system in raw format. That's all I want to do.

Please help me if you have any pointers/suggestions to make this work.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like its defaulting to the page size on the system? Have you tried using the bs flag?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using the `bs` flag, but that does not make any difference.